# Generic Razor Type Parameter pass as variable

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, razor, blazor-webassembly

Razor/Blazor component with Generic Type Parameter as a variable

```
 <QueryRow  Titem="Person"/>
```

Works

in the above component i can recieve the parameter

```
 Type typeParameterType = typeof(Titem);
```

and create an instance

```
 object? myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(typeParameterType);
```

That all works great, however

```
  public Type mytype = typeof(Person);

  <QueryRow  Titem="@mytype"/>
```

Does not work, I need be able to pass the types down from the parent as list of types or strings I can convert to real types using reflection.

How do I pass the type parameter as a variable such as

```
mytype = typeof(Person);
```

I can do all this in code but not in razor!!! what am I doing different/ wrong ?

for example, Person starts as a string below

```
   Type? typeArgument = Type.GetType("Person");
   Type genericClass = typeof(QueryRow<>);
   Type constructedClass = genericClass.MakeGenericType(typeArgument);
   object? createdType = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedClass);
```

works great, but then I have to use blazor's Dynamic component as a workaround to do the render, which I'd rather avoid as it seems a bit yuk

Comment: Have you tried `@mytype.FullName`? `Titem` is expecting a string, not a type object.

Comment: Hi , thanks. for commenting I have tried that thing is Titem is a TypeParameter using razor's @typeparam it will not accept a string only a type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a variable as the type parameter in this way.

You can create a RenderFragment using a bit of reflection:

```
public Type myType = typeof(Person);

@MakeQueryComponent(myType)

@code {
    RenderFragment MakeQueryComponent(Type typeParam)
    {
        var genericType = typeof(QueryRow<>)
            .MakeGenericType(new[] { typeParam });

        RenderFragment frag = new RenderFragment(b =>
        {
            b.OpenComponent(1, genericType);
            b.CloseComponent();
        });

        return frag;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Following [GitHub issue 26781](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26781), the Blazor team have now encapsulated the above method of generating a RenderFragment into a new component called DynamicComponent.

See [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Components/src/DynamicComponent.cs) and [guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Hi, Thanks agreed I could not find a way, that being said, why did you choose to use RenderTree directly , instead of Dynamic Component? if you could explain that or change it Dynamic then i'll mark it as accepted

Comment: Simple answer:  I was not familiar with DynamicComponent!  I learned to use RenderFragment directly since before DynamicComponent was introduced.  Have just done some research.  I may too start to use DynamicComponent in places.  Will update the answer to reflect the options.